# Check a Value and Tag according to that value and append in same row using shell

Tags: bash, shell, unix, awk, gawk

I have a file as
 `NUMBER|05-1-2016|05-2-2016|05-3-2016|05-4-2016|`
`0000000  | 0 | 225.993 | 0 | 324|`
`0003450  | 89| 225.993 | 0 | 324|`
`0005350  | 454 | 225.993 | 54 | 324|`

In example There are four dates in the header
I want to check the value under  the date for the field 1 'number' and tag values according to that using shell
example if value is between 0-100 tag 'L' and if greater than 100 , tag 'H'
So the output should be like
 `NUMBER|05-1-2016|05-2-2016|05-3-2016|05-4-2016|05-1-2016|05-2-2016|05-3-2016|05-4-2016|`
`0000000  | 0 | 225.993 | 0 | 324| L | H | L | H|`
`0003450  | 89| 225.993 | 0 | 324|L | H | L | H|`
`0005350  | 454 | 225.993 | 54 | 324|H | H | L | H|`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick and dirty example, that:

- sets the input and output field separator (`-F` and `OFS` below) to `|`,
- prints the the header (record with `NR==1`)
- for all others prints the fields 1-5, and then executes function `lh` for fields 2-5
- defines the function lh, as one returning `L` for values < 100, and `H` for all others

Code:

```
awk -F \| '
BEGIN {OFS="|"}
NR==1 {print}
NR > 1 {print $1, $2, $3, $4, $5, lh($2), lh($3), lh($4), lh($5) }
function lh(val) { return (val < 100) ? "L" : "H"}
' file.txt
```

Alternative function `lh`:

```
function lh(val) {
    result = "";
    if (val < 100) {
        result = "L";
    } else {
        result = "H";
    }
    return result;
 }
```

Comment: thanks but what if conditions are more than 2 , i actually have 5.Sorry for bothering .

Comment: You can extend the `lh` function